# how can a SPARQL Query on Website

Tags: c#, css, sparql, rdf

I learned from rdfdotnet wiki. How can a SPARQL Query a Website?
If I understand that correctly I must first to write a endpoint 
than the query string with `SparqlParameterizedString queryString`
or with String.
Then, I write

```
SparqlResultSet results = endpoint.QueryWithResultSet(queryString);
```

My code:

```
//Define a remote endpoint
        //Use the DBPedia SPARQL endpoint with the default Graph set to DBPedia
        SparqlRemoteEndpoint endpoint = new SparqlRemoteEndpoint(new Uri("http://localhost:10080"));//, "http://localhost:10080");

        //Create a Parameterized String
        SparqlParameterizedString queryString = new SparqlParameterizedString();

        //Add a namespace declaration
        queryString.Namespaces.AddNamespace("lf-maint", new Uri("http://linkedfactory.org/vocab/maintenance#"));
        queryString.Namespaces.AddNamespace("foaf", new Uri("http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/"));
        queryString.Namespaces.AddNamespace("rdfs", new Uri("http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"));

        //Set the SPARQL command
        //For more complex queries we can do this in multiple lines by using += on the
        //CommandText property
        //Note we can use @name style parameters here
        queryString.CommandText = "select ?l { ?s a lf-maint:Fault; lf - maint:description ?l filter(lang(?l) = \"de\") }";

        SparqlParameterizedString.ExecuteQuery Method (IRdfHandler, ISparqlResultsHandler)

        //Make a SELECT query against the Endpoint
        //Exception muss noch geschrieben werden VDS.RDF.Query.RdfQueryException
        try
        {
            //retun ist eine HttpWebResponce
            endpoint.QueryRaw(queryString);
            SparqlResultSet results = endpoint.QueryWithResultSet(queryString);     
            foreach (SparqlResult result in results)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
            }

        }
        //Exception für VDS.RDF.Query.RdfQueryException
        catch (RdfQueryException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error RdfQueryException: " + e);
        }
        //Exception für den VDS.RDF.Parsing.RdfParserSelectionException
        catch(RdfParserSelectionException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error RdfParserSelectionException: " + e);               //bekomme fehler beim Parsen
        }


        //Make a DESCRIBE query against the Endpoint
        IGraph g = endpoint.QueryWithResultGraph("DESCRIBE ");
        foreach (Triple t in g.Triples)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(t.ToString());
        }
```

my libarys:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using VDS.RDF.Parsing;
using VDS.RDF.Query;
using VDS.RDF;
```

Comment: *"How can a SPARQL Query a Website"* (this is far away from a valid English sentence...)-> I don't understand this sentence and therefore, I don't understand what you're asking for. What does **not** work with your current code? You have to set a triple store and a SPARQL query. Nothing more, nothing less. Is there a SPARQL service at `http://localhost:10080`? Most triple stores do have some additional suffix, e.g. `/sparql` or something similar. Which triple store do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I expressed myself in a hurry a little bad.
The point is that I can do a SPARQL query on the URI.
I would like to do this via a C # program. So that I can later embed this code in another program.
But I'm not quite sure how it works. What are the most important functions for this? Is my code a good start? I can not reach a query with it.